# overloading () operator for unordered_set

Tags: c++, c++11, unordered-map, unordered-set

I have a class, whose objects I put into a unordered_set. 
To do this I have written custom hash generators and comparators to be able to use the class objects in unordered_set. Everything works fine. The comparator of this class looks like this :

```
struct MyClassComparator
{
  bool
  operator()(const MyClass & obj1, const MyClass & obj2) const
  {
    if (obj1.getName() == obj2.getName())
      return true;
    return false;
  }
};
```

So I am comparing the names (strings) of the objects (nothing fancy). I use this to find a MyClass object in a set using `.find` function.

Now the question is : 
Is it possible to over load this () operator resulting in the following code

```
struct MyClassComparator
{
  bool
  operator()(const MyClass & obj1, const MyClass & obj2) const
  {
    if (obj1.getName() == obj2.getName())
      return true;
    return false;
  }

  bool
  operator()(const MyClass & obj1, const std::string & name) const
  {
    if (obj1.getName() == name)
      return true;
    return false;
  }
};
```

and use the `.find` function like

```
my_set.find("my_class_name")
```

if yes is there a performance overhead in doing so.

Comment: `if (MyClass.getName() == MyClass.getName())` would appear to always test true? Did you intend `obj1` and `obj2`?

Comment: yes i intended it to be obj1 and obj2. Thank you for pointing out I changed it now.

Comment: what you are trying to create is a transparent comparator which I think `unordered_set` will not make use of

Comment: `std::unordered_set<T, ...>::find` only accepts a `const T&`, so you will find no benefit from overloading `operator()` like you have. You will also require that `MyClass` is implicitly constructible from a `const char[14]`/`const char*` for the call to find to compile. To be fair, you will not have a performance overhead by adding this `operator()` to the overload set, but you will also observe no benefit.

Comment: @ThomasRussell so you mean to say that in the call my_set.find("my_class_name"), it will not take the overloaded () into consideration and always use the first one with `const T& ` ?

Comment: how do you pass the comparator to the map? In the constructor?

Comment: @user463035818 yes I do.

Comment: would be cool if you add that line, because I have the feeling that the essential part (where the overload is chosen) is missing from your code here. See also [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`std::unordered_set::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/find) takes a `const Key& key` argument so if you want to be able to use `my_set.find("my_class_name")` then `MyClass` must be constructible from `const char[]`.

This will create a temporary key used as parameter for `find`. I wouldn't worry about performance at all at this stage. It would be a premature optimization.

I recommend using `std::string` instead of plain C string:

```
struct MyClass
{
     MyClass(const std::string& s);
};
```

and then:

```
using namespace std::string_literals;
my_set.find("my_class_name"s);
```

---

also, as a side note

```
 if (obj1.getName() == obj2.getName())
      return true;
 return false;
```

can be rewritten in a simpler way (I recommend it):

```
return obj1.getName() == obj2.getName();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search using data types other than `std::unorderd_set::value_type`, you want a map, not a set.

```
class MyClassMap {
   public:
     myclass_map::iterator insert( MyClass& object ) {
        return _map.insert( object.get_Name() );
     }

     myclass_map::iterator find( MyClass& object  ) {
       myclass_map::iterator it = _map.find( object.getName() );
       if( it != _map.end() && it->getName() == object.getName() )
          return it;
       return _map.end();
     }

     myclass_map::iterator find( const std::string& name ) {
       return _map.find(name);
     }


   private:
     typedef std::unordered_map<
         const std::string&,
         MyClass*,
         MyClassHash,
         MyClassComparator
       > myclass_map;

     myclass_map _map;
};
```

Comment: I don't know about the map ... searching is not the same as indexing

Comment: I get your point. However, OP's question talks about searching.